# Window.onsvgload not firing in ajax loaded file

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

I have an svg-file being loaded in a page. I am also using SVG Web. On that page I use

```
window.onsvgload = function() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

This is working fine when the file is opened directly. However, when I'm ajax-loading the file, it does not fire. The document.ready is firing. Does any one know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery svg plugin if you're using the jQuery library: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html